# Pods "Pending" on Google Kubernetes Engine because of new "priority" field

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes cluster on GKE that's managed by Helm, and recently deploys started failing because pods would not leave the `Pending` state. Inspecting the pending pods I see:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From                                                Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----                                                -------
  Normal   Scheduled         50m                default-scheduler                                   Successfully assigned default/my-pod-6cbfb94cb-4pzl9 to gke-staging-pool-43f2e11c-nzjz
  Warning  FailedValidation  50m (x6 over 50m)  kubelet, gke-staging-pool-43f2e11c-nzjz  Error validating pod my-pod-6cbfb94cb-4pzl9_default(8e4dab93-75a7-11e9-80e1-42010a960181) from api, ignoring: spec.priority: Forbidden: Pod priority is disabled by feature-gate
```

And specifically, this warning seems relevant: `Error validating pod my-pod-6cbfb94cb-4pzl9_default(8e4dab93-75a7-11e9-80e1-42010a960181) from api, ignoring: spec.priority: Forbidden: Pod priority is disabled by feature-gate`

Comparing the new, `Pending`, pods with currently running pods, the only difference I see (apart from timestamps, etc) is:

```
$ kubectl get pod my-pod-6cbfb94cb-4pzl9 -o yaml > /tmp/pending-pod.yaml
$ kubectl get pod my-pod-7958cc964-64wsd -o yaml > /tmp/running-pod.yaml
$ diff /tmp/running-pod.yaml /tmp/pending-pod.yaml
…
@@ -58,7 +58,8 @@
       name: default-token-wnhwl
       readOnly: true
   dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
-  nodeName: gke-staging-pool-43f2e11c-r4f9
+  nodeName: gke-staging-pool-43f2e11c-nzjz
+  priority: 0 // <-- notice that the `priority: 0` field is added
   restartPolicy: Always
   schedulerName: default-scheduler
…
```

It appears that this started happening some time between May 1st, 2019, and May 6th 2019.

The cluster I've used as an example here is a staging cluster, but I've noticed the same behavior on two similarly configured production clusters, which leads me to believe there was a change on the Google Kube side.

Pods are deployed by Helm through `cloudbuild.yaml`, and nothing has changed in that setup (either version of Helm, or cloudbuild file) between May 1st and May 6th when the regression seems to have been introduced.

Helm version:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.8.2", GitCommit:"a80231648a1473929271764b920a8e346f6de844", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.8.2", GitCommit:"a80231648a1473929271764b920a8e346f6de844", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: what is your Kubernetes version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the docs for [Pod priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/) the feature is `alpha` in `<= 1.10` (disabled by default, enabled by a feature gate which GKE doesn't do on the control plane, afaik) then it became `beta` in `>= 1.11` (enabled by default).

Could be either or combination:

1. You have a GKE control plane `>= 1.11` and the node where your Pod is trying to start (being scheduled by the kube-scheduler) is running a kubelet `<= 1.10`. Somebody could have upgraded the control plane without upgrading the nodes (or instance group)
2. Someone upgraded the control plane to 1.11 or later and the priority admission controller is enabled by default and it's preventing Pods with the `spec.priority` field set from starting (or restarting). If you see the [API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#pod-v1-core) (priority field) it says that when the priority admission controller is enabled you can't set that field and that field can only be set by a [PriorityClass/PriorityClassName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass).

Comment: It looks like this was the issue: the master was updated to 1.11, while the nodes were still running 1.8. Upgrading the nodes required a bit of manual work: after clicking "upgrade nodes" in the control panel, I had to force kill the pods suck in Pending before each node would upgrade… but after that the upgrade went smoothly and everything seems to be working. Thanks!